# 'While' loop is not exiting after set number of seconds

Tags: mysql

The goal here is to make it busy for 'n' seconds and then exit.
This is latest version of code. I tried direct `date1 < date2` in `while`, etc

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `DelayResponse`(pSeconds int) RETURNS varchar(1)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE x int;
    DECLARE EndDateTime datetime ;
    DECLARE CurrDateTime datetime ;
    Set x = 0;
    set EndDateTime = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL pSeconds second); 
    set CurrDateTime = now(); 

    WHILE x = 0 DO
        -- expecting to set x to 1 in pSeconds but nope
        if  CurrDateTime > EndDateTime then 
            set x = 1;
        end if;
        SET CurrDateTime = now(); 
    END WHILE;
    RETURN 'X';
END$$
delimiter ;

select DelayResponse(5) X
```

I can't get out the loop here. What am I missing?

Another version that does not work. Just spins `running...` not ending

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `DelayResponse`(pSeconds int) RETURNS varchar(1)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE x int;
    DECLARE EndDateTime datetime ;
    Set x = 0;
    set EndDateTime = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL pSeconds second); 

    WHILE x <= 0 DO
            set x = now() - EndDateTime;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN 'X';
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why do this on the server? This looks pretty punishing since it causes the procedure to spin and use 100% CPU until that time comes up.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your input. But this is one-time thing that will not be running any time in applications. This is for unit testing

Comment: Interesting. It works as expected if you make it a procedure rather than a function.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work (as a function only apparently), but you should be able to make it even more succinct simply with `WHILE now() < EndDateTime DO` doing nothing within the loop.

Comment: @Barmar YES! just tried it and voila. MySql bug? v5.7.12

Comment: There's also a built-in `SLEEP()` function that does this.

Comment: @Uueerdo this is where I started

Comment: Yes it seems like a bug to me. I don't see anything in the list of restrictions on stored functions that indicates this is a known limitation.

Comment: It seems specific to using `NOW()`. If I change the loop so it just increments a counter, it works fine.

Comment: @Barmar Certainly, `DO SLEEP(pSeconds);` works in function. I will now need to see if I will get same error in .net app that calls it.... In my case, I need strictly timing, not counter. Thank you!

Comment: @T.S. I know you need timing, I was just using that to narrow down the bug.

Comment: @Barmar After all, MySql team did find a bug whilre running the function. They say - "... your function is in the state of "Opening tables".". I don't know what this mean, but they found something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is a result of a documented, but less-known feature of [now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). So, this is **not a bug**!

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored **function** or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the **function** or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which returns the exact time at which it executes.

So, while @Barmar is correct in suggesting the use of `sleep()`, you can make your original code work with `sysdate()` instead of `now()`.

Comment: Yep! good work. I would never think of this. Your answer is IT!

Comment: @T.S. I bumped into this feature a couple of years ago when the timestamps in a long running update were the same, even though the query was running for over a minute.

Comment: Yea, looks like big difference vs Sql Server/Oracle, where `GetDate()/systimestamp` are guaranteed being same only for a single statement. Basically, those are != `now()`

Comment: I highlighted "function" in your answer because in Procedure it works. I think, that now I know why this is like that - function can be used in SQL. And SQL execution guarantees same result no matter how many times you call now().  And trigger might be same thing - because trigger used against table data while executing DML, so same thing

Comment: @T.S. A function is always executed as part of a statement, while a procedure can contain multiple statements.

Comment: Interestingly, MySql team looked into this and found "...function is in the state of "Opening tables", in v5.7 and 8.0. don't know what this means yet, but there is a bug after all. Your answer, however, stands

Comment: @Shadow A procedure is also executed as part of a `CALL` statement. And functions contain statements just like procedures do. It's really hard to see this as anything other than a special case for functions and triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `SLEEP()` function instead of your own loop.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `DelayResponse`(pSeconds int) RETURNS varchar(1)
BEGIN 
    DO SLEEP(pSeconds);
    RETURN 'X';
END$$
delimiter ;

select DelayResponse(5) X
```